# SceneManager can't recognize LoadSceneAsync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I imported a project from an earlier version Unity, I'm currently using 2018.3

I got one Issue, I can't seem to ignore It, commenting it gives me another error

> Assets\Scripts\Generals\LoadController.cs(48,22): error CS0117: 'SceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'LoadSceneAsync'

I do not have a defined class named 'SceneManager' that's overriding the unity SceneManager Class

LoadController.cs

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public string nameSceneLoad = "MainGame";
 void NextScene()
{
    CancelInvoke();
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync (nameSceneLoad, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

If I try to ignore It I'll have the following

> Assets\Photon Unity Networking\Editor\PhotonNetwork\PhotonViewHandler.cs(188,13): error CS0433: The type 'EditorSceneManager' exists in both 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEditor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

PhotonViewHandler.cs

```
//TODO: check if this can be internal protected (as source in editor AND as 
dll)
public static void LoadAllScenesToFix()
{
string[] scenes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.unity", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string scene in scenes)
{
EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(scene);
PhotonViewHandler.HierarchyChange();//NOTE: most likely on load also 
triggers a hierarchy change
EditorSceneManager.SaveOpenScenes();
}
Debug.Log("Corrected scene views where needed.");
}
```

[image: Screan]
Any ideas ?

I tried Navigating to the defintion F12 leads to

```
#if !UNITY_MIN_5_3  && ! UNITY_2017 
// in Unity 5.3 and up, we have to use a SceneManager. This section re- 
implements it for older Unity versions

#if UNITY_EDITOR
namespace UnityEditor.SceneManagement
{
/// <summary>Minimal implementation of the EditorSceneManager for older 
Unity, up to v5.2.</summary>
public class EditorSceneManager
{
    public static int loadedSceneCount
    {
        get { return 
  string.IsNullOrEmpty(UnityEditor.EditorApplication.currentScene) ? -1 : 1; }
    }

    public static void OpenScene(string name)
    {
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.OpenScene(name);
    }

    public static void SaveOpenScenes()
    {
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.SaveScene();
    }

    public static void SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo()
    {
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.SaveCurrentSceneIfUserWantsTo();
    }
}
}
#endif

 namespace UnityEngine.SceneManagement
{
 /// <summary>Minimal implementation of the SceneManager for older Unity, up 
to v5.2.</summary>
 public class SceneManager
  {
    public static void LoadScene(string name)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(name);
    }

    public static void LoadScene(int buildIndex)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(buildIndex);
    }
  }
 }

 #endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying which one to use to bypass the duplicated `EditorSceneManager` error like this:

```
using foo = UnityEditor.EditorSceneManager;
using boo = otherdll.Namespace;
```

BTW I think this error is because you have a DLL in .NET 4.x and a previous DLL from .NET 3.5, so you can probably just delete the one that is for 3.5.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, where do I find this dll

Comment: I try to navigate to the definition F12

Comment: Not in a unity enviroment, because at work but look at the dependencies tab or references dunno the name its under your main project folder in the solution explorer view(inside vs), it has icon which looks like two or more connected gray rectangles(btw if you are still using the .net 3.5 this is sure not the error)

Comment: Your comment tho as far as i understand it somehow at improting unity implemented a basic, Scenemanager for you which is does not contain a def. for loadasync so you basically have two SceneManager classes, can you link those Macros values?

Comment: I changed this line #if !UNITY_MIN_5_3  && ! UNITY_2018
now the error are gone but it looks like this is due comptability issue I'll have to downgrade

Comment: If the project is not that big, you can upgrade your project manually tbh, however your asset which caused the second error might be broken with never versions :/